What do I need to know as a user about authorising applications that interact with Stack Exchange?
I know that I can grant permission of an application to do something with my account on the network. What can and cannot an application do if I allow it? For example, if I see a description like:


Identify your account
Access your private actions and information
Create and change content on your behalf
Read your global inbox
Keep these permissions perpetually


How can I figure out exactly what this encompasses?

The Stack Exchange API offers a number of things an application can do. This description is going to be light on technical details as those can be looked up in the documentation. However, we still need to cover the basics:
What is authorisation?
The API can be used anonymously but with limitations. An application can ask to be authorised which will soften these limitations. The authorisation allows it to act as a given user. This can help with traceability of actions but also can open up new actions that could not be used anonymously.
An application can ask a user to authorise it. This is an explicit action where the user will need to confirm.
Scopes
Authorisations come with scopes. Each time an application asks for access, it has to explicitly list which scopes it wants access to. This could also be none (which limits the amount of things that can be done). The scopes are:

read_inbox1 - access a user's global inbox
no_expiry1 - access_token's with this scope do not expire
write_access1 - perform write operations as a user
private_info1 - access full history of a user's private actions on the site
manage_collective_recommendations2 - access recommending a post in a Collective
manage_collective_reports1 - access to reports by Collectives

Which action requires which scope (if any) is documented further down.
1 from the API documentation
2 only documented at individual actions
Expiration
Access to an application will be limited in time unless the no_expiry grant is requested. With it, the access will be perpetual.
Manual revocation
As a user, you can always revoke access you have given to an application:

Go to your user profile (on any site).
Go to the Settings tab.
Go to Authorized applications on the right.

From here you can de-authorise any application you have have used at any point.
Write access
An application can request write access at which point it will be able to do actions in the user's name. For example, posting or flagging will require write access.
This can be dangerous, so accept it with caution.
However, do keep in mind the following:

If the application needs to do any one action that require write access, it still can only request write access to everything. For example, if the application only seeks to delete a comment, it cannot do that without also be able to post answers.
As a user, you can always revoke access at any time.
Write access is still monitored for abuse. Applications found to abuse it can have its access invalidated it without the users needing to do anything.

What can the API do?
This is information available from the overview as well as the detailed information for each method. Formatted as a single table for convenience.
Stack Exchange API v2.3



API endpoint
Description
Authorisation required?
Scope required




answers
Get all answers on the site.
-
-


answers/{ids}
Get answers identified by a set of ids.
-
-


answers/{id}/accept
Casts an accept vote on the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{id}/accept/undo
Undoes an accept vote on the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{ids}/comments
Get comments on the answers identified by a set of ids.
-
-


answers/{id}/delete
Deletes the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{id}/downvote
Casts a downvote on the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{id}/downvote/undo
Undoes a downvote on the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{id}/edit
Edits the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{id}/flags/options
Returns valid flag options for the given answer.
auth required
-


answers/{id}/flags/add
Casts a flag on the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{ids}/questions
Gets all questions the answers identified by ids are on.
-
-


answers/{id}/upvote
Casts an upvote on the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{id}/upvote/undo
Undoes an upvote on the given answer.
auth required
write_access


answers/{id}/recommend
Casts a recommendation on the given answer.
auth required
write_access and manage_collective_recommendations


answers/{id}/recommend/undo
Undoes an recommendation on the given answer.
auth required
write_access and manage_collective_recommendations


answers/{id}/suggested-edit/add
Creates a suggested edit on an existing answer.
auth required
write_access


badges
Get all badges on the site, in alphabetical order.
-
-


badges/{ids}
Get the badges identified by ids.
-
-


badges/name
Get all non-tagged-based badges in alphabetical order.
-
-


badges/recipients
Get badges recently awarded on the site.
-
-


badges/{ids}/recipients
Get the recent recipients of the given badges.
-
-


badges/tags
Get all tagged-based badges in alphabetical order.
-
-


collectives
Get all Collectives on the site, in alphabetical order.
-
-


collectives/{slugs}
Get Collectives identified by a set of slugs.
-
-


collectives/{slugs}/questions
Get questions identified by a set of slugs.
-
-


collectives/{slugs}/answers
Get answers identified by a set of slugs.
-
-


collectives/{slugs}/tags
Get tags identified by a set of slugs.
-
-


collectives/{slugs}/users
Get users identified by a set of slugs.
-
-


collectives/{slugs}/reports
Get reports identified by a set of slugs.
auth required
manage_collective_reports|{slug}


collectives/{slugs}/reports/add
Creates a new report request for the Collective
auth required
-


comments
Get all comments on the site.
-
-


comments/{ids}
Get comments identified by a set of ids.
-
-


comments/{id}/delete
Delete a comment identified by its id.
auth required
write_access


comments/{id}/edit
Edit a comment identified by its id.
auth required
write_access


comments/{id}/flags/add
Casts a flag on the given comment.
auth required
write_access


comments/{id}/flags/options
Returns valid flag options for the given comment.
auth required
-


comments/{id}/upvote
Casts an upvote on the given comment.
auth required
write_access


comments/{id}/upvote/undo
Undoes an upvote on the given comment.
auth required
write_access


events
Get recent events that have occurred on the site. Effectively a stream of new users and content.
auth required
-


info
Get information about the entire site.
-
-


posts
Get all posts (questions and answers) in the system.
-
-


posts/{ids}
Get all posts identified by a set of ids. Useful for when the type of post (question or answer) is not known.
-
-


posts/{ids}/comments
Get comments on the posts (question or answer) identified by a set of ids.
-
-


posts/{id}/comments/add
Create a new comment on the post identified by id.
auth required
write_access


posts/{id}/comments/render
Renders a hypothetical comment on the given post.
-
-


posts/{ids}/revisions
Get revisions on the set of posts in ids.
-
-


posts/{ids}/suggested-edits
Get suggested edits on the set of posts in ids.
-
-


privileges
Get all the privileges available on the site.
-
-


questions
Get all questions on the site.
-
-


questions/{ids}
Get the questions identified by a set of ids.
-
-


questions/{ids}/answers
Get the answers to the questions identified by a set of ids.
-
-


questions/{id}/answers/add
Creates an answer on the given question.
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/answers/render
Renders a hypothetical answer to a question.
-
-


questions/{id}/close/options
Returns valid flag options which are also close reasons for the given question.
auth required
-


questions/{ids}/comments
Get the comments on the questions identified by a set of ids.
-
-


questions/{id}/delete
Deletes the given question.
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/downvote
Casts a downvote on the given question.
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/downvote/undo
Undoes a downvote on the given question.
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/edit
Edits the given question.
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/favorite
Bookmarks the given question. (Previously known as "favoriting" a question)
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/favorite/undo
Undoes bookmarking the given question. (Previously known as "favoriting" a question)
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/flags/add
Casts a flag on the given question.
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/flags/options
Returns valid flag options for the given question.
auth required
-


questions/{ids}/linked
Get the questions that link to the questions identified by a set of ids.
-
-


questions/{ids}/related
Get the questions that are related to the questions identified by a set of ids.
-
-


questions/{id}/suggested-edit/add
Creates a suggested_edit on an existing question.
auth required
write_access


questions/{ids}/timeline
Get the timelines of the questions identified by a set of ids.
-
-


questions/{id}/upvote
Casts an upvote on the given question.
auth required
write_access


questions/{id}/upvote/undo
Undoes an upvote on the given question.
auth required
write_access


questions/add
Creates a new question.
auth required
write_access


questions/featured
Get all questions on the site with active bounties.
-
-


questions/no-answers
Get all questions on the site with no answers.
-
-


questions/render
Renders a hypothetical question.
auth required
-


questions/unanswered
Get all questions the site considers unanswered.
-
-


questions/unanswered/my-tags
Get questions the site considers unanswered within a user's favorite or interesting tags.
auth required
-


revisions/{ids}
Get all revisions identified by a set of ids.
-
-


search
Search the site for questions meeting certain criteria.
-
-


search/advanced
Search the site for questions using most of the on-site search options.
-
-


similar
Search the site based on similarity to a title.
-
-


search/excerpts
Searches a site.
-
-


suggested-edits
Get all the suggested edits on the site.
-
-


suggested-edits/{ids}
Get the suggested edits identified by a set of ids.
-
-


tags
Get the tags on the site.
-
-


tags/{tags}/info
Get tags on the site by their names.
-
-


tags/moderator-only
Get the tags on the site that only moderators can use.
-
-


tags/required
Get the tags on the site that fulfill required tag constraints.
-
-


tags/synonyms
Get all the tag synonyms on the site.
-
-


tags/{tags}/faq
Get frequently asked questions in a set of tags.
-
-


tags/{tags}/related
Get related tags, based on common tag pairings.
-
-


tags/{tags}/synonyms
Get the synonyms for a specific set of tags.
-
-


tags/{tag}/top-answerers/{period}
Get the top answer posters in a specific tag, either in the last month or for all time.
-
-


tags/{tag}/top-askers/{period}
Get the top question askers in a specific tag, either in the last month or for all time.
-
-


tags/{tags}/wikis
Get the wiki entries for a set of tags.
-
-


users
Get all users on the site.
-
-


users/{ids}
Get the users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{ids}/answers
Get the answers posted by the users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{ids}/badges
Get the badges earned by the users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{ids}/comments
Get the comments posted by the users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{ids}/comments/{toid}
Get the comments posted by a set of users in reply to another user.
-
-


users/{ids}/favorites
Get the questions bookmarked (previously known as "favorited") by users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{ids}/mentioned
Get the comments that mention one of the users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{id}/network-activity
Gets a user's activity across the Stack Exchange network.
-
-


users/{id}/notifications
Get a user's notifications.
-
read_inbox


users/{id}/notifications/unread
Get a user's unread notifications.
-
read_inbox


users/{ids}/posts
Get all posts (questions and answers) owned by a set of users.
-
-


users/{id}/privileges
Get the privileges the given user has on the site.
-
-


users/{ids}/questions
Get the questions asked by the users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{ids}/questions/featured
Get the questions on which a set of users, have active bounties.
-
-


users/{ids}/questions/no-answers
Get the questions asked by a set of users, which have no answers.
-
-


users/{ids}/questions/unaccepted
Get the questions asked by a set of users, which have at least one answer but no accepted answer.
-
-


users/{ids}/questions/unanswered
Get the questions asked by a set of users, which are not considered to be adequately answered.
-
-


users/{ids}/reputation
Get a subset of the reputation changes experienced by the users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{ids}/reputation-history
Get a history of a user's reputation, excluding private events.
-
-


users/{id}/reputation-history/full
Get a full history of a user's reputation.
auth required
private_info


users/{ids}/suggested-edits
Get the suggested edits provided by users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{ids}/tags
Get the tags that the users (identified by a set of ids) have been active in.
-
-


users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-answers
Get the top answers a user has posted on questions with a set of tags.
-
-


users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-questions
Get the top questions a user has posted with a set of tags.
-
-


users/{id}/tag-preferences
Get a given user's tag preferences.
auth required
private_info


users/{id}/tag-preferences/edit
Edit a user's tag preferences.
auth required
write_access and private_info


users/{ids}/timeline
Get a subset of the actions of that have been taken by the users identified by a set of ids.
-
-


users/{id}/top-answer-tags
Get the top tags (by score) a single user has posted answers in.
-
-


users/{id}/top-question-tags
Get the top tags (by score) a single user has asked questions in.
-
-


users/{id}/top-tags
Get the top tags (by score) a single user has posted in.
-
-


users/moderators
Get the users who have moderation powers on the site.
-
-


users/moderators/elected
Get the users who are active moderators who have also won a moderator election.
-
-


users/{id}/inbox
Get a user's inbox.
auth required
read_inbox


users/{id}/inbox/unread
Get the unread items in a user's inbox.
auth required
read_inbox


access-tokens/{accessTokens}/invalidate
Allows an application to dispose of access_tokens when it is done with them.
-
-


access-tokens/{accessTokens}
Allows an application to inspect access_tokens it has, useful for debugging.
-
-


users/{id}/achievements
Get a user's recent network-wide achievements.
auth required
-


apps/{accessTokens}/de-authenticate
Allows an application to de-authorize itself for a set of users.
-
-


errors
Get descriptions of all the errors that the API could return.
-
-


errors/{id}
Simulate an API error for testing purposes.
-
-


filters/create
Create a new filter.
-
-


filters/{filters}
Decode a set of filters, useful for debugging purposes.
-
-


inbox
Get a user's inbox, outside of the context of a site.
auth required
read_inbox


inbox/unread
Get the unread items in a user's inbox, outside of the context of a site.
auth required
read_inbox


notifications
Get a user's notifications, outside of the context of a site.
auth required
read_inbox


notifications/unread
Get a user's unread notifications, outside of the context of a site.
auth required
read_inbox


sites
Get all the sites in the Stack Exchange network.
-
-


users/{ids}/associated
Get a user's associated accounts.
-
-


users/{ids}/merges
Get the merges a user's accounts has undergone.
-
-



What about that bulleted point list in the question?


Identify your account


It will require you, as a user, to authenticate the application.


Access your private actions and information


The application will request the private_info scope.


Create and change content on your behalf


The application will request the write_access scope.


Read your global inbox


The application will request the read_inbox scope.


Keep these permissions perpetually


The application will request the no_expiry scope, thus can keep this access until it is revoked.
